# Passing meta_box string to post__in?

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

Hey Guys,
I'm using a meta box to store a bunch of page ID's. When I try to pass the page ID's to the post__in parameter of WP_Query it doesn't work becuase the metabox comes throug as a string, when it needs to be a comma separated integers.

So, say the "relatedpages" meta box contains: 55, 33, 22

```
$relatedpages = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'relatedpages', true);

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'order'         => 'ASC',
    'orderby'       => 'menu_order',
    'post__in'      => array($relatedpages)
    );

$myposts = get_posts($args);
echo $myposts;
```

The problem is that $related pages is now "55, 33, 22" rather than 55, 33, 22

How can I overcome this? Is there a way to store just the integers in the meta box, rather than converting them to a string?

Thanks,
Drew

Comment: By the way, to *store* ids, you're using a custom field. To *input* those ids you're using a custom metabox.

Comment: Hey scribu, am I just using the wrong words in my question, or should I be storing my ID's differently?

Comment: Well, since you asked: http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'post__in'      => explode( ',', $relatedpages )
```

Comment: Cast to int whilst we're there? `array_map( 'absint', explode( ',', $relatedpages ) )` ...

Comment: That's done anyway in WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but in the end I think the problem was the 'post__in' parameter can't be used in get_posts like I wanted. As per the [codex for get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), 'include' is the way to do it.

```
$relatedpages = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'relatedpages', true);

$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
    'include'           => $relatedpages
    );

$myposts = get_posts($args);
```

Thanks anyway!